# Some Devices needs clear all aplication data while other not

Tags: flutter, mobile-application, flutter-hive

Recently I publish my mobile application but there is a unique problem. In some devices people download application in google play and easily use the application. But some devices has need to clear all application data from settings then open again because if they don't do this they can't see onboarding screen and also can't fetch data from internet. In flutter I basically use Hive local storage at main dart to route after installation

```
//Here if onBoard box is true user will see welcomescreen
if (Hive.box('settings').get('onBoard') == true) {
screen = const WelcomeScreen();
}
//Here if user already registered but click sign out button isRegistered box will be false and user
//will go LoginPage again

else if(Hive.box('settings').get('isRegistered') == false){
screen = const LoginPageDesign();
}
//! If on boarding not true (false or null) user will route OnBoarding page
else {
screen = const OnBoarding();
}
```

Comment: I realized that this problem happens with ANDROID 10 version ! I send a message to google team but if anyone know the answer it would be great for everyone

Answer (score 0):

The problem is some android devices backsup local storage data to the cloud. You can go through this article from android: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html

So, to overcome this issue, just navigate to your AndroidManifest and do the following just under application tag:

```
<application
...
android:allowBackup="false"
android:fullBackupContent="false"
tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
...
</application>
```

Comment: I make these change and I also change if else notation to switch. I made internal testing and it get fixed with Android 13 but still problem with Android 10

Answer (score 0):

```
 switch(Hive.box('settings').get('isRegistered')){
  
  case null:
  screen = const OnBoarding();
  break;

  case false:
  screen = const LoginPageDesign();
  break;

  case true:
  screen = const WelcomeScreen();
  break;
```

}

Interestingly once I tested with internal test,
Android 13 real devices has no problem it goes first onBoaring but with Android 10 it goes directly WelcomeScreen I don't understand how it is possible to take true for this situation should always null at fresh start.

EDIT : Problem is interestingly fixed once add another Hive.box for registeration ...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).